# Fetch Specific Data From A website and Turn it into PDF

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler, fetch

I Need to Fetch Specific data from [ERPNEXT.COM/User-Guide](http://ERPNEXT.COM/User-Guide) to make it look like 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-uyX-vtnUFINnlhRWJ6cWNtMDg/view?usp=sharing

Simply i want to remove Header and footer so that only the main Heading and article with images will remain .. this i want to do on the whole website and fetch this data either using php or anything and then convert it to PDF. I was using Acrobat pro to convert these webpage to PDF and make a user guide PDF for users . Also i was using httrack to download complete website but that fetchs all data .

Please suggest A complete solution .

Regards,
Vishal Verma

Answer (score 0):

read url with this function :

```
function fetchURL($URL) {
        $Max=200000;
        $handle = @fopen ($URL, "r");
        if ($handle === false){ return false; }
        $len = 0;
        $buffer = "";
        while (!feof($handle)){
            $queue = fgets($handle, 4096);
            $buffer .= $queue;
            $len = $len + strlen($queue);
            if($len > $Max){ fclose ($handle); unset($buffer); return 0; break;}else{continue;}
        }
        fclose ($handle);
        return $buffer;
    }
```

if you want get pdf only check character from that function substr(fetchURL([URL]),0,4) ==='%PDF'. that url is pdf. in my case i write the result to disk in file.pdf. i hope this help